# Windows Phone 8 DateTime Formatting

Tags: parsing, windows-phone-7, datetime, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to convert a date string to datetime. but it doesn't work, I know there are a few datetime posts on stackoverflow, however I couldn't come across the specific one I am having

```
     DateTime.ParseExact("22-07-2013", "dd-MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

I simply want to format the string to "22 Jul", but it gives me a system.format exception

am I missing something?

thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date you're trying to parse and the format you're using are inconsistent.

If you want to parse "22-07-2013" like shown in your example, use the format `dd-MM-yyyy`:

```
 DateTime.ParseExact("22-07-2013", "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

If you want to parse "22 Jul" like you're saying in the question, use the format `dd MMM`:

```
 DateTime.ParseExact("22 Jul", "dd MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: with .ToString("dd MMMM")) to fully answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this ....

```
                DatePicker date = new DatePicker();
                DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(date.ValueString);
```